# How to integrate api.ai bot with any booking site to book/order something?

Tags: webhooks, chatbot, dialogflow-es, facebook-chatbot, diagflow

I've made a chatbot who can talk to people and make a normal conversation. I want to develop that chatbot so that user is able to, say order a pizza from Dominoz.com or Book a ticket on expedia or add something to cart in ebay. 
I've made the bot using Google's Api.Ai (diagflow). How can I integrate it with any site performing some kind of transaction. Answer with an example booking/ordering site would be highly appreciated. 
Just for additional info: I think it is possible by that webhook option in fulfillment section. But how exactly? How to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if there are APIs available for ordering/booking through Expedia/eBay. Dominos have exposed their APIs for ordering purposes. Following is the link for bot ordering pizza & node-dominos-api

https://hellotars.com/bot-examples/featured/pizza-ordering-chatbot/

http://riaevangelist.github.io/node-dominos-pizza-api/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F68HtCtJbGA

Webhook in Dialogflow is something where your actual logic lies. You can write it in any language you're confident of & host it somewhere for Dialogflow to communicate with it. There are 2 API references v1 & v2. Your web service receives a POST request from Dialogflow. Your request/response to/from webhook should include mandatory fields mentioned at following links:

https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment

https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/query